# image processing： How to count the number of convex regions of a target in binary image?

Tags: image-processing, binary-image

[image]

This is a binary image, I want to count the number of convex regions,but I don't know how to do it,I hope you can help me.

Comment: I have no sure approach. I'd lowpass this thing, then calculate a contour, and analyze its curvature. the curvature should have four corresponding extrema. perhaps do the lowpass on the contour itself, before calculating curvature

Answer (score 1):

Compute the convex hull of the blob and count the sections that touch it.

[image]